# Проблеми при установки React.js

Tags: javascript

[image]

Здравствуйте. Никак не могу решить данную проблему. Скорее всего она связана с node.js и npm. Также подобную ошибка встречалась мне в gulp и я так и не смог ее решить. Пробовал разными способами перевстановлював несколько раз Node.js. Искал на форумах ну так и ничего подходящего не нашел. Кто сталкивался с подобной ошибкой пожалуйста напишите буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не скачивают в oneDrive используйте другой путь